# Spring Boot 2.7.11 - DNS Resolution Problem at start on Apple M1 Ventura OS

Tags: java, spring-boot, dns

I'm facing a issue while running spark-submit command on my mac (Apple M1 pro Ventura 13.6 ) with openjdk11 and  spring boot version 2.7.17.
Error message is like `Unable to load io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider`, fallback to system defaults. How to resolve this issue?
I tried adding below dependency, but didn't resolved the issue.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
  <classifier>osx-aarch_64</classifier>
</dependency>
```